# Magento - Check if specific category is active

Tags: php, magento

Is there any way of checking if one specific category is active?  I have a hard coded navigation and I want to show or hide a link depending on the active status of a specific category.  Perhaps something like this:

```
// Check to see if the Sale category is active...
$specificCatID = '90';    
if(isCategoryActive($specificCatID)){
    // Specific category is active, do something
}
```

I have searched high and low, and have yet to get close to being able to solve this.  Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I hope this will answer your question :)

```
$specificCatID = '90';
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($specificCatID);

if ($category->getIsActive()) {
}
```